# Make 2d array from single array and fill the StringGrid

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

Part of my code:

```
int y[1000];
//Generation of array

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender){
 Memo2->Clear();
 for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
  y[i]=rand()%1000;
  Memo2->Lines->Add(IntToStr(y[i]));
 }
}
```

The task is to make 2 dimensional 10x10 array and fill the StringGrid as I have below. I can't find the right algorithm to do this.  Can someone offer some advice?

```
11 19 20 24 25
10 12 18 21 23
4  9  13 17 22
3  5  8  14 16
1  2  6  7  15
```

Comment: I dont see in your code any algorithm for determining the row/column. As a note, you are filling the grid diagonally across (if you have not determined that already)

Comment: @Javia1492 If i knew how to do that, i wouldn't ask here) I didn't find the right alghorithm in google)

Comment: Are you displaying just a general number variation where it increases diagonally? Or is this a fixed number set of 1-25?

Comment: @Javia1492 i made that just to show what i need to realize, how my random numbers should fill the stringgrid/ There many alghorithms in internet how to fill 2d array diagonally from left top corner. but it isn't what i need/ Sory for my bad english)

Comment: Minor edits for grammar and language.  Well written and easy to understand questions are more likely to receive useful answers. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer sorry for my bad english) I'm from Ukraine. and when i'm trying to explain what i need it's hard a little bit to operate with programming definitions. I'm just a begginer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets work with your 5x5 grid for simplicity, but you can apply the same concepts to other grid sizes.

Set `i` to 0.  This is the index into a 1D `int values[25]` array, starting with the first value.

Set `x` to 0 and `y` to 4. These are the indexes into a 2D `int grid[5][1]` array, starting in the bottom-left corner, controlling the forward motion of the fill.

Set `direction` to 1. This is the number that `x` and `y` are incremented on each iteration, controlling the sideways motion of the fill.

Loop `i` from 0 to 24. For each iteration, copy `values[i]` into `grid[x][y]`, then increment `x` and `y` by `direction`, then check some conditions:

- if `x` and `y` have exceeded 4x4 (the bottom-right corner), decrement `x` by 1 and `y` by 2 and multiply `direction` by -1.
- otherwise, if `x` and `y` have exceeded 0x0 (the top-left corner), increment `x` by 2 and `y` by 1 and multiply `direction` by -1.
- otherwise, if `y` has exceeded 4 (the bottom edge), decrement `y` by 1 and multiply `direction` by -1.
- otherwise, if `x` has exceeded 0 (the left edge), increment `x` by 1 and multiply `direction` by -1.
- otherwise, if `y` has exceeded 0 (the top edge), increment `x` by 2 and `y` by 1 and multiply `direction` by -1.
- otherwise, if `x` has exceeded 4 (the right edge), decrement `x` by 1 and `y` by 2 and multiply `direction` by -1.

You will eventually reach the final corner and your loop will run out of values to copy.

The code ends up looking something like this (which I am sure can be simplified with some more advanced mathematics than I care to delve into):

```
const int numX = 5;
const int numY = 5;
const int numValues = numX * numY;

int grid[numX][numY];
int values[numValues];

for(int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i)
{
    // for demo purposes...
    values[i] = i+1;//rand()%1000
}

int x = 0;
int y = numY-1;
int dir = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i)
{
    grid[x][y] = values[i];

    x += dir;
    y += dir;

    if ((x >= 0) && (x < numX))
    {
        if (y < 0)
        {
            x += 2;
            y += 1;
        }
        else if (y >= numY)
        {
            y -= 1;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    else if ((y >= 0) && (y < numY))
    {
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        else // x >= numX
        {
            x -= 1;
            y -= 2;
        }
    }

    else if ((x >= numX) && (y >= numY))
    {
        x -= 1;
        y -= 2;
    }

    else // (x < 0) && (y < 0)
    {
        x += 2;
        y += 1;
    }

    dir = -dir;
}

// use grid as needed...
```

The result:

[image: 5x5]

Here is 10x10:

[image: 10x10]

Now play around with different values of `numX` and `numY`.  They don't have to be the same value, just > 0. For example:

11x2:
[image: 11x2]

3x7:
[image: 3x7]

10x1:
[image: 10x1]

1x10:
[image: 1x10]